# How to compare two (non-zero-terminated) character arrays

Tags: string, delphi

Say I have two character arrays `A, B: array[1..255] of Char` and their respective lengths `LA, LB: Byte`. I would like to compare them most efficiently. But:

- Building `string`s (e.g. via `SetString`) and doing `SA < SB` seems wasteful.
- `StrComp` doesn't work as the arrays aren't necessarily zero-terminated.
- `StrLComp(PChar(@A[1]), PChar(@B[1]), Min(LA, LB))` doesn't work for e.g. "Foo" and "Foobar".

Is there any built-in function I can use?

Comment: I'm left scratching my head as to why we can't just write if a = b.

Comment: @alcalde: I mean comparing equivalent to `s1 < s2` where `s1` and `s2` are `string`s.

Comment: @alcalde - The junk/remaining chars might also differ in case of a should be equal A,B (eg: foo/foo), a=b would check for whole length (255).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StrLComp(@A[1], @B[1], Min(LA, LB))` does the job. But you need to add an extra test on the two lengths. If `StrLComp` returns 0 then you need to compare `LA` and `LB`.

```
cmp := StrLComp(@A[1], @B[1], Min(LA, LB));
if cmp = 0 then
  cmp := LA - LB;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call [`CompareString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which accepts lengths of the strings to compare:

```
var
  cs: Integer;
begin
  cs := CompareString(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, @A[1], LA, @B[1], LB);
  Win32Check(cs <> 0);
  case cs of
    CSTR_LESS_THAN: 
    CSTR_EQUAL: 
    CSTR_GREATER_THAN: 
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sertac! I'll check that tomorrow.